# How to work out lifting capacity of a motor with a power rating in newtons?

Tags: motor, torque

I am building a "dumb waiter" (it is a small lift to move glasses, plates and stuff from the basement, up a vertical shaft to the ground floor). I wish to use a garage door motor as my lifting device.

This particular motor is power rated at 1000 newtons. Could anyone advise me if this will be able to lift +/- 40 kg? This would be the maximum I believe I would ever need to lift. Will it have enough torque? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can lift almost anything you want, since the motor is not rated in newtons, but in newton-meters, and you can always gear it down to lift an arbitrarily heavy object - just slowly.

Comment: Power (watts) = Newton\*meters/second. So to find your lifting capacity calculate Newtons = Power\*time to lift/distance to lift or Power = 60\*RPM\*pully radius (meters)\*gear ratio and work out a gearing ratio to suit. But if your winch says 1000N (and I'm assuming it's a winch as regular motors aren't rated in Newtons) then it can lift 40kg as 1kg is 9.8 Newtons (for back-of-the-envelope stuff, 10N/kg is good enough) that gets you ~100kg of lifting capacity (again, assuming that the 'motor' really *is* rated in Newtons)

Comment: Also make sure you've got some reliable mechanical braking in places to prevent any, um, breaking and potential injury. A 40kg dumb waiter suddenly dropping when your hands are inside it would be rather dangerous. Something should positively mechanically latch when the motor is stationary and it should be impossible to open the door with the latch not engaged.

Comment: 1000 Newtons is probably the rating for the fully assembled opener. It is around 220 lbs, or 100 kgf (roughly). If you are using it in that fashion, with the rail that comes with the opener, then it will easily lift 40 kg. If you extracted the motor from the opener, then the answer is, it will work if you use the right gearing or block and tackle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughts and input. Yes Ian, I have locking latches planned as well as a physical break.

Comment: Sam, That's great, thanks. I'm using the garage door opener as is, with the track attached. The only spec I can obtain is rated in newtons...which really had me stumped. Your calculation appears to give me more than enough power needed to lift my counterbalanced "trolley". Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A motor rating in Newtons makes no sense.  That's the same as rating your car engine in pounds.  Perhaps this "motor" is rated for the weight of garage door it can lift *with the mechanical system of a particular model* around it.

Before you are ready to spec a motor, you have to find the power your dumbwaiter needs.  Decide the maximum loaded weight of the whole mechanism, and then the maximum time you are willing to let it take to get from the lowest to the highest points.  The force that must be applied to the dumbwaiter mechanism times the distance is the total energy required to lift it.  That divided by the time you want it to take is the power.  Of course there will be friction losses, so the power input to the mechanism must be higher.  I'd add at least 50% extra.  No matter what else, the motor must be rated for at least this much power, else it simply can't perform the task.

The other degree of freedom that must be specified for the motor can be expressed as the torque it puts out at the desired power.  The mechanical linkage between the motor and the dumbwaiter mechanism converts the torque from the motor to a force on the dumbwaiter.  You have some leeway here since this mechanical mechanism can be made with a reasonably wide ratio.  You need to know what the motor torque is to pick the ratio, but you can work with any motor torque within reason, as long as the motor can supply the power.

Comment: Thank you Olin. I'm afraid Newtons is the only "power rating" the technical specs give. This is why I was asking on this forum - lots more educated people here than I.  I will be adding a counterbalance to the lift so only the weight of the items in the lift will need to be moved up or down.